# Differentiate Slash type, Hash type and Simple(no-trailing-delimiter) Namespaces

Tags: xml, namespaces, rdf, jena, semantic-web

I am a newbie to the Semantic Web.
I have been encountering the different types of namespaces while learning Jena Programming. For example:

Hash Type Namespace:
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"

Slash Type Namespace:
xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/

Simple Namespace:
xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb"

Please explain the difference between all three kinds of the namespaces mentioned here. If there are other some other types of namespaces, then please share those with your answer too.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HashVsSlash, https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/#solutions, https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-vocab-pub/.

Answer (score 3):

The last one is not simple at all. Lack of a delimiter means that, when used to prefix a local name, you will lose the ability to split the absolute IRI back into namespace and local name. It is most likely to cause confusion to other ontology users.

As for the other two, there is no difference in the functionality of an IRI that uses one or the other - the main difference is in how toolchains can use the information. The links provided by Stanislaw in the comment are a good start.